# Adding a Primary Key to an Existing Database in Advantage

Tags: sql, primary-key, advantage-database-server

What is the syntax to add a Primary Key to an existing Production database? I have inherited a database with no Primary Keys set for anything, and I need a primary key on each table to use my ORM for an application.

I tried googling to no avail, Advantage's documentation isn't the best in the world.

Comment: It does seem to support some of the `alter table add primary key` syntax: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11/index.html

Comment: Using `ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY (column)` throws me an error: Expected lexical element not found: <identifier> You are missing the column names.

Comment: Maybe it wants a name for the constraint (this is often optional)

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT p_key PRIMARY KEY (column)` gives me the same error. :/

Comment: `Advantage's documentation isn't the best in the world.` Understatement of the century, those guys are utterly useless and I hope they go out of business soon so I don't have to support it anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tables in free connections don't support a primary key. (They do support unique indexes however.)

Tables in dictionaries support primary keys by the table property `TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY`.

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/master_sp_modifytableproperty.htm

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_ModifyTableProperty(
    'TableName'
  , 'TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY'
  , 'IndexName'
  , 'RETURN_ERROR'
  , NULL
)
```

You have to add a unique index using the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` statement first.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IndexName ON TableName (ColumnName)
```

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/master_create_index.htm